# How to extarct text from file with id?

Tags: python, pandas, file

i have two files. one contains id  and the other contains sentences for each id but with little changes like this example

File1 :

```
111_3232
111_ewe2
111_3434
222_3843h
222_39092
```

File2 :

```
111   some_text_1   some_text_1
222   some_text_2  some_text_2
```

i need to make a file with id and its sentences like

```
111_3232   some_text_1   some_text_1
111_ewe2   some_text_1   some_text_1
111_3434   some_text_1   some_text_1
222_3843h  some_text_2  some_text_2
222_39092  some_text_2  some_text_2
```

I tried this code

```
import os 

f = open("id","r")
ff = open("result","w")
fff = open("sentences.txt","r")
List = fff.readlines()    
i =0 
for line_id in f.readlines():
    for line_sentence in range(len(List)):
        if line_id in List[i]:
            ff.write(line_sentence)
        else : 
            i+=1
```

but got

```
if line_id in List[i]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

as I got the whole line from file2, not id only... is there any way better than i make

EDIT

i tried to use panads but I'm not familiar with it well by this code

```
df = pd.read_csv('sentence.csv')    
for line_id in f.readline():
    for line_2 in df.iloc[:, 0] :
       for (idx, row) in df.iterrows():
            if line_id in line_2:
                ff.write(str(row) +'\n')
            else : 
                ff.write("empty" +'\n')
```

but got the wrong data as I couldn't catch the right row well

Comment: What's up with the whitespace? I wrote a solution in Pandas assuming you were using two spaces for column delimiters and the other whitespace was significant, but I got a different result. For example, the way I'm doing it, row 2 in `File1` is parsed as `['222', ' some_text_2', 'some_text_2']` (note the leading space in the second cell). So it seems like whitespace is not actually significant for you, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic approach

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as fd1, open('file2.txt', 'r') as fd2:
    lines1 = fd1.read().split() # remove \n
    lines2 = fd2.readlines()

new_text = ''
for l1 in lines1:
    for id_, t1, t2 in (l.split() for l in lines2):
        if l1.startswith(id_):
            new_text += f'{l1} {t1} {t2}\n'

with open('file3.txt', 'w') as fd:
    fd.write(new_text.strip())
```

Comment: Thanks alot , i tried it but got `for id_, t1, t2 in (l.split() for l in lines2):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`

Comment: @sammo I checked with exactly the same data as in the question and works. Could it be that in file 2 some_text1 or 2 contain white spaces?

Comment: the files2 contains tab character after each column

Comment: @sammo That's it! I assumed white spaces! (was not clear, sorry!)

Comment: i fixed it Thanks a lot `l.split('\t')`

Comment: in case here the updates: `l.split('\\t')` and `f'{l1} {t1} {t2.strip()}\n'` if columns in File2 are separated by `\t`

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving the result is to store the `sentences` and `file_id` pair in a dictionary and iterate over the id file content to get the result

```
sentences_dict = {}
# read all sentences into a dictionary as key value pair
with open("sentences.txt", "r") as sentences_file:
    for line in sentences_file.read().splitlines():
        split_lines = line.split(" ")
        sentences_dict.update({split_lines[0].strip():  "  ".join(split_lines[1:])})

result_file = open("result.txt", "w")

# iterate over id file and match the starting text
with open("id.txt", "r") as id_file:
    for file_id in id_file.read().splitlines():
        txt = sentences_dict.get(file_id.split("_")[0], "")
        result_file.write(f"{file_id}{txt}\n")
        
result_file.close()
```

Make sure to always close a file explicitly unless you are opening along with the `with` keyword.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i tried your answer but got the ids only without its text

Comment: Then either your sentences file doesn't have a record for the file id or the file content format isn't in similar pattern as provided in the example above. The code works for the sample file content provided above.

Comment: i think I got where is the problem the dictionary when i print it to see its content I read `{'f77a619f6ccc449f915b44bdc0d6d8f0\tWell': '` it took the first word from the second column i don't why as I separated them in columns